# Does Android broadcast when an app is opened?

Tags: android, broadcast

For example, if I want to know when Youtube is opened, is there any broadcast associated with it? I know of course I can poll the logcat message to check the activity. But can I do it through broadcast since it will be much less power-hungry.

This link seems to indicate it is impossible:<
[How to Track App Usage in Android? How to detect when an activity is launched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012361/how-to-track-app-usage-in-android-how-to-detect-when-an-activity-is-launched)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In adroid, is there any broadcast when some app is opend?

No, for obvious privacy reasons.