# calculate app uptime - android

Tags: android, battery, usage-statistics

I am trying to get the power consumption details made by each installed app in a list. But since I **do not have root access**, I know I won't be able to use `adb` shell commands to get battery usage info for all processes.

What I think I can do is get the **uptime** for each installed app, get the total time my battery has been disconnected (by saving timestamp when `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED` happens), and calculating -

( app_runtime * 100 ) / total_time_battery_disconnected

However, I am unable to obtain the most basic info about an app -> how long it has been running ? I can use **activeSince** on RunningServices, but that is not the solution here.

The class `ApplicationInfo` does not provide any such methods either.

Is there any  way to get this detail ?
I see so many bloatware apps showing my the total consumption made by every app I have installed with the *running since* time also shown, so I know it is possible. But how ?

I looked into [this article](https://www.apteligent.com/technical-resource/battery-life-how-does-the-android-battery-tool-work-and-why-should-developers-care/) on Android Battery Life. But this is limited to Android internals.

Even tried [UsageStats](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStats.html), but its not working, returning Zero when querying usage stats list.

Comment: if you are looking for simple time your app was running? try firebase analytics https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics

Comment: r u talking about own app or other installed device app?

Comment: @VishalPatel I want to see running time of other apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html) should do what you are asking for. Not sure why it's not working, perhaps you need this in your manifest?

```
<uses-permission
      android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
      tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Here's a sample logging the UsageStats

```
long startTime = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 0, 1).getTimeInMillis();
long endTime = new GregorianCalendar(2017, 0, 1).getTimeInMillis();

UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager)context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
List<UsageStats> queryUsageStats = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, startTime, endTime);

for (UsageStats us : queryUsageStats) {
    Log.d(TAG, us.getPackageName() + " = " + us.getTotalTimeInForeground());
}
```

This page has [an example](http://blog.tunebrains.com/develop/2015-10-20-usage-stats-manager-sample/) that walks you through the process of getting the persmission from the user. Lastly, here a [full sample on GitHub](https://github.com/ColeMurray/UsageStatsSample).

**Prior to API 21** - The SDK does not provide a mechanism to get application usage statistics. The only way to do it would be to poll the [ActivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) using the [getRunningTasks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)) or [getRecentTasks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRecentTasks(int,%20int)) functions. I'll direct you to [CommonsWare's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9012522/1943229) to a similar question.

Comment: Thanks but UsageManager is applicable only for API 21 and above.

Comment: I updated my answer. Although, it's not good news, so maybe that's why you haven't responded to the update.

Comment: I changed my approach and instead of getting uptime for the running apps, I calculated the [memory consumed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getProcessMemoryInfo(int[])) for each running service, and since I knew the available memory the system had, I calculated percentage of RAM being used by each process and ranked them in that order, which is basically what Android Developer Options gives us when we click on Running Services (in Settings).